# Compiling php_excel (v1.0.0) and LibXL (v3.5.4.1) on Windows

Tags: php, windows, compilation

I've tried to compile the PHP extension php_excel (v1.0.0) on VC9 with no luck, anyone able to provide guidance? I've used notes found on the web for compiling other PHP extensions as a reference but there are so many unknowns, I'm not a C developer so please bear with me. I would like to know how to compile extensions but if someone was able to just compile it for me I would still very much appreciate it.

**Update: Step-by-step process below to SUCCESSFULLY compile the php_excel extension**

```
INSTALLATION
============
Install Microsoft Windows Server 2003 x86 incl. Service Packs
Install Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0
Install Microsoft Windows SDK v6.1 (6.0.6001.18000.367-KRMSDK_EN.iso)
Install en_visual_studio_2008_professional_x86_dvd_X14-26326.iso
Install en_visual_studio_2008_service_pack_1_x86_dvd_x15-12962.iso
Install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1
Extract php-sdk-binary-tools-20110915.zip to C:\php-sdk
Extract deps-5.3-vc9-x86.7z to C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc9\x86\deps
Extract php-5.3.28-src.zip to C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc9\x86\php-5.3.28

Open Microsoft Windows SDK v6.1 > CMD Shell

COMMANDS (to compile PHP)
=========================
setenv /x86 /xp /release
cd /d c:\php-sdk\
bin\phpsdk_setvars.bat
bin\phpsdk_buildtree.bat phpdev
cd /d C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc9\x86\php-5.3.28
buildconf
configure --help
configure --enable-apache2-2handler --with-curl --enable-fileinfo --enable-mbstring --enable-mbregex --with-mcrypt --with-openssl --with-pgsql --enable-sockets --with-mysql --with-mysqli --enable-pdo --with-pdo-mysql --with-pdo-mssql --with-pdo-pgsql --enable-soap --with-xmlrpc --with-xsl
nmake
nmake clean all

LibXL (additional steps)
========================
Extract php_excel-1.0.0.zip to C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc9\x86\php-5.3.28\ext\excel
Extract \libxl-3.5.4.1\include_c\* to C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc9\x86\deps\include\libxl
Extract \libxl-3.5.4.1\lib\libxl.lib to C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc9\x86\deps\lib\libxl.lib
buildconf
configure --with-excel=shared
nmake
```

**php_excel (branch v1.0.0)**
https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel/tree/v1.0.0

**LibXL for Windows 3.5.4**
http://www.libxl.com/download.html

**System:**

- Windows Server 2003 R2
- PHP 5.3
- Apache 2.2
- php_excel 1.0.0
- LibXL 3.5.4.1
- Visual Studio 2008 (VC9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapshots was made available under http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/excel/20140606/

Though I'm not sure there's no legal issue redistributing the libxl that way, so no guarantee for how long the builds may stay there. If you're intended to continuously use this library, please decide to file an issue to the origin repository about proposing the extension to PECL. Being in PECL will bring many advantages as we'll be able to continuously support it, also automatic builds will be available.

For building extensions yourself, see https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild . The most important thing regarding VC9 - be sure using service pack 1. Be informed that everyone is welcome to ask questions on PECL mailing lists and #php.pecl on efnet.

Just to mention - as alternative you could use the com_dotnet extension available in the core to achieve the goals.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I've atleast upgraded now from 0.9.1 to 0.9.9 using the excel snaphot extension from 20140606. Waiting on the 1.0.0 version :-)

Comment: I've asked the question at #php.pecl on efnet so hopefully that'll solve my issue. "As there's a new version of php_excel released please could this be added to the PECL snapshots for excel? Current snapshot @ http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/excel/20140606/ is version 0.9.9, however the latest is 1.0.0. Many thanks"

Comment: That snapshot is from the 1.0.0 tag. Just as it's missing the package.xml, the build system doesn't recognize the version to put into the package name. I know why you see that in phpinfo(), https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel/blob/v1.0.0/excel.c#L66 - the usual "version disease" :)

Comment: Was php_excel removed from PECL? I cannot find it there anymore: http://pecl.php.net/excel

Answer (score 1):

I've set up a github repository for building php_excel with VC11. It may help you to compile php_excel for VC9. see https://github.com/johmue/win-php-sdk-builder

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking for the latest Windows builds of php_excel.dll: I have upgraded all my builds to php_excel from git head at https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel, combined with the latest LibXL.

My Windows builds can be found at http://www.apachelounge.com/viewforum.php?f=6

All flavours are available: PHP 5.3/5.4/5.5/5.6/7.0/7.1/7.2/7.3/7.4, TS/NTS, x86/x64. The zips contain a phpinfo.htm with more info on all the extensions in the builds.

Before compiling new PHP-versions I always do a git pull from the master repositories, so hopefully the php_excel.dll's will be up-to-date for a long time.